# How to write singles() to a file

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, io, stream

For debugging purposes I need to write an array of single() to a new file but I don't find any example. 
Since I am trying to debug something, I don't want to trust my own instincts on how to do that.
Can anybody show me?

Is this the correct way?
I am so afraid I might have introduced an error.

```
Public Sub WriteSinglesToFile(ByVal uSingles() As Single, ByVal uPath As String)

    Using fs As New FileStream(uPath, FileMode.Create)
        Using bw As New BinaryWriter(fs)
            For Each no In uSingles
                bw.Write(no)
            Next
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BinaryWriter.Write` method to write the Singles

```
Public Sub WriteSinglesToFile(ByVal uSingles() As Single, ByVal uPath As String)
    Using writer As IO.BinaryWriter = New IO.BinaryWriter(IO.File.Open(uPath, IO.FileMode.Create))
        For Each uVal As Single In uSingles 
            writer.Write(uVal)
        Next
    End Using 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is for debugging... he probably wants something human readable.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn You may be right. I tend to take questions literally.

Comment: The funny things is that @Joel Coehoorn 's approach results in a different output than yours so I wonder which one is correct.

Comment: @tmighty They are both "right" This code writes the binary representation of the Singles, Joel's writes the string representation.

Comment: I will expect the file with a hex editor, so I am not looking for any advanced solutions. Am I then right selecting @Blackwood 's answer as THE answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-liner:

```
Public Sub WriteSinglesToFile(ByVal uSingles() As Single, ByVal uPath As String)
    'The "R" is for "Round-trip". 
    ' It ensures what you read back later matches what you had originally
    File.WriteAllLines(uPath, uSingles.Select(Function(s) s.ToString("R")))
End Sub
```

In case you want to read these back later:

```
'Assumes file written by above code...
Public Function ReadSinglesFromFile(ByVal uPath As String) As IEnumerable(Of Single)
    Return File.ReadLines(uPath).Select(Function(l) Single.Parse(l))
End Sub
```

Comment: What does round-trip mean please?

Comment: Floating point numbers are not exact. If you're not careful, what you write out to a stream may not be read back in as the exact same number. The round-trip format makes sure to write out a number that will be read back as the same value, rather than something slightly different. Since this is for debugging, that may not be a concern, and you can use any format you want. Docs are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx